# Can an AJAX code (Node.js) be written which does not send any response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

If there is no data to send in response to an AJAX request, we don't need to send a response ? Is it true, I have read somewhere that every request has a response. But if we don't send a response, would not server throw an error? a bit confused about this.

Comment: Yes you can call a AJAX which does not send a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http is a request/response protocol.  Every incoming http request should send a response of some sort.  Both clients and servers are designed around that.

If the request was received properly, but there is no data to be sent back, then just respond with a 200 status or in some cases a 204 (no content).

If there is an error condition but no data to send back, then send back a 4xx or 5xx status (depending upon what is appropriate).

Sending back a response without any data just sends the status code and headers with no body.  That is perfectly fine and appropriate.

If you don't send a response, then several undesirable things can happen.  First, the client will be waiting for a response, holding the socket resource open and eventually timing out.  Second, any client code is likely waiting for some sort of confirmation that the http request was received properly (usually waiting for a 2xx or 3xx status code) so the client code may not proceed with its next steps until it get confirmation.  Third, the socket will stay open on the server until the client times out and closes the socket or until the server times out and closes the socket, also consuming unnecessary resources for the duration of the timeout.  This can impact the scalability of your server if lots of connections are hanging out all the time waiting to timeout.  It can also fill up logs with errors about timed out connections.

In a particularly bad case in a browser, the browser implements a connection limit per host and will create a maximum number of connections (a pretty small number) of simultaneous connections to the same host.  If several connections to a particular host are just sitting there without sending a response waiting to time out, this can severely limit the number of connections available for actual data transfer as the browser will just queue other requests, waiting for the prior ones to finish.

Comment: Yes, a good example of that will be delete request. we dont need to send anything back as the response data in delete req.